# issue reading links with selenium in C#(in some sites)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I save site links with the following code, But in some sites, I encounter the following error:

OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: 'stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
(Session info: chrome=xx.x.xxx.xx)

**problem with(this site): https://namnak.com**

```
private string followlinks(string url)
{

IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\");

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);


//...
//...
//...
foreach (var item in driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a")))
            {
              
                var url2 = item.GetAttribute("href");
        //...

         }

}
```